# DS18B20 / onewire stopped working after dist-upgrade

Tags: pi-4, update, ds18b20

I recently did `apt-get update` + `apt-get dist-upgrade` and after reboot my DS18B20 stopped working.

`ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/` results in:

```
 w1_bus_master1
```

But previously I had dirs for my two sensors there.

In dmesg I noticed that there is an error message:

```
gpio-4 (onewire@0): enforced open drain please flag it properly in DT/ACPI DSDT/board file
```

I don't know if it is related as I don't know if it was pre-upgrade.

I have Raspberry Pi 4 (first version) and kernel `4.19.97-v7l+`.

My sensors are correctly connected to GPIO 4, there is a pull-up resistor, and the whole config was working perfectly for 4 years (previously on Rpi 3 and even more previously on Rpi 1).

Comment: I suggest you revert the software to an earlier version.

Comment: @joan How should I do that? I suspect the kernel is the issue, but I don't know what version I had previously (I don't remember when I did upgrade last time).

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=165590